# How load another screen after tapping on the button?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, loading

I want to make something like loading screen between screens.

Actually I have made Options Screen, where you can choose difficulty and number of questions.
[image]

When you tap on the button and choose difficulty (like on screenshot) you should have loading screen. How can I make it? Then after some time it should navigate to  Quiz Screen with questions.

I have tried put Timer inside initState() below

> Navigator.pop(context);

but it doesn't work.

Also I want to use [Loading Animation Widget](https://pub.dev/packages/loading_animation_widget), to look this better.

My code

```
void _startQuiz() async {
    setState(() {
      processing = true;
    });
    try {
      List<Question> questions =
          await getQuestions(widget.category, _numberOfQuestions, _difficulty);
      Navigator.pop(context);
      

      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => QuizScreen(
                    questions: questions,
                    category: widget.category,
                  )));
      
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      
      setState(() {
        processing = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you loading anything during the loading screen? It's highly discouraged to just have a timer for a couple seconds and make the user wait for nothing

Comment: I'm loading questions from Trivia API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i get from your issue was, you want to show Loading once getQuestions still in progress, if i'm correct here is my simply suggestion

```dart
  bool loading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
         body: loading ? YourLoadingScreenWidget : <Your Menu Widget>; //
      )
    );
  }

  void _startQuiz() async {
    setState(() {
      processing = true;
      loading = true; //Enable loading before getQuestions
    });
    try {
      List<Question> questions =
          await getQuestions(widget.category, _numberOfQuestions, _difficulty);
      //Navigator.pop(context); //I'm not sure why you pop the screen
      setState(() {
        loading = false; 
      });
      

      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => QuizScreen(
                    questions: questions,
                    category: widget.category,
                  )));
      
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      
      setState(() {
        loading = false; 
        processing = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Here's my GitHub if you want to see how look the rest of code: https://github.com/Arkadiusz4/Quiz-App/blob/main/lib/screens/options_screen.dart

Answer (score 0):

Best Scenario for this.In the next page that will appear after the user choose difficulty to use **FutureBuilder** Widget.The progress indicator will  appear first until the page load.

```
  Future grab_data(){
    //your grabbed data
}



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test page'),
      ),
      body:SingleChildScrollView(

        child:FutureBuilder(
          future:grab_data() ,
          builder: (context,snapshot){
           if(snapshot.hasData){
             
             return Container(
               child: Text("here what you want to display"),
             );
             
           }
           
           return CircularProgressIndicator(); //this is loading progress indicator that appear until the build complete
          },
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
```